# No corresponding object layer type could be found for the conceptual type

Tags: entity-framework

I have been trying to convert a status table in my database to be an enum that I can access from code.

The initial setup was a Status table with the few entries I needed included (e.g. Active, Inactive etc).  To convert I did as follows:

- Open up EDMX file in Visual Studio 2013, Find Status table and click "Convert to enum" on "Id" field.
- Changed all references in code where the "Id" field was being set to an Int (cast from enum).

My solution builds and deploys just fine now. The problem is the following error:

```
No corresponding object layer type could be found for the conceptual type
```

I get the feeling that the code knows the way the database should be, but the database has not yet been configured.

How can I fix this? Thank you.

Please note that my Entity Framework approach is Database First.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make sure your enum name matches the type name.  So for example if the enum is lets say "MyProject.Fully.Qualified.EnumName.MyEnum" Should be called "MyEnum" when you create the enum type.

Comment: Not sure what this means? The enum name should match which type name?

Comment: @Le-roy unfortunately YES :-(

Comment: Well this sucks.

Comment: Just to add clarity around "the type name"; in my case I was using the "Reference external type" for the enum in my EDMX - it is this type name which must match the internal EDMX's enum's type name.  It does indeed suck as the EDMX designer was fine for me to unwittingly click OK and generate it!

Comment: Gotta love it when after 7 years you find yourself on the internet, researching the same problem. Here I was in April 2017 

Answer (score 5):

In my case I needed to declare my `Enum` as `Byte` which is the type I was using in the table property with Entity Framework.

Example:

```
Public Enum DataState As Byte
    Normal=0
    Deleted=1
End Enum
```